# MongoDB ObjectID Generating rule affect the order of insert

Tags: mongodb

I am a new Mongodb user ,From the MongoDB Official  Document [links](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)
it  shows :

> Returns a new ObjectId value. The 12-byte ObjectId value consists of:
>
> ```
> a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> a 5-byte random value, and
> a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
> ```

In my limit experience with  mongodb  I think  it is just like   this
  timestamp + randomvalue + counter

here is  my questions
1. The generated random number is smaller than the random number generated by the previous insert  in  one second .  the order of data insert  and  the order  of  data's ObjectID  is  not the same ? is it?
2 .  the  counter  is also started  with a random value. I think  the counter's max value is 2^3*8   (2^24) ,  but  when  the counter  started  with a very big  value . what will happened ? (I  mean  will this  influencing the total amount of written data ？  and  the insert order )

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

At last .I find some document  about this question .

> sorting on an _id field that stores ObjectId values is roughly
>   equivalent to sorting by creation time.
>
> IMPORTANT
>
> While ObjectId values should increase over time, they are not
>   necessarily monotonic. This is because they:
>
> Only contain one second of temporal resolution, so ObjectId values
>   created within the same second do not have a guaranteed ordering, and
>   Are generated by clients, which may have differing system clocks.

this document show . They are not orderly in some condition .

Comment: [links](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)